# In vim remapping, how do I "capture" and reuse "any" character?

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc, I have the following which, in insert mode, nicely adds a semi-colon to the end of the line and returns the cursor to its original spot:

```
inoremap <leader><leader>; <C-o>mp<C-o>A;<C-o>`p
```

How can I do the same but for ANY/ALL characters? For example, something like this pseudocode:

```
inoremap <leader><leader><any> <C-o>mp<C-o>A<any><C-o>`p
```

Or using regex, something like this pseudocode...

```
inoremap <leader><leader>(\w) <C-o>mp<C-o>A$1<C-o>`p
```

Is it even possible to capture and reuse like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
inoremap <expr> <leader><leader> "<C-o>mp<C-o>A" . (nr2char(getchar())) . "<C-o>`p"
```

To break it down, there is a command for inoremap called `<expr>`.  This command changes inoremap to look like this: `inoremap <expr> {keys} {function}`  When you press the keys defined in the `{keys}` section, it will call a function in the `{function}` section and insert the return value of that function.  Anything in quotes in the `{function}` section will be inserted.  So, here is the breakdown of the function section:

```
"<C-o>mp<C-o>A" . (nr2char(getchar())) . "<C-o>`p"
       ^                   |                 ^
       |-------------------|-----------------|
These just do              |
what the original          |
mapping does               |
                  This just gets a single character
                  from the user and concatenates it to your
                  original mapping, in place of the ';'
```

Read these for more information on these topics:

```
:help :map-<expr>
:help getchar()
:help nr2char()
```

**Note:** `getchar` doesn't actually take from the mapping itself, it just prompts the user for a character, then inserts it.

Comment: Really nice! Thanks. I think you have a `n` typo at the beginning (and also forgot the `\`p` to return to original spot). So, in sum: `inoremap <expr> <leader><leader> "<C-o>mp<C-o>A" . (nr2char(getchar())) . "<C-o>\`p"` ... works really nicely.

Comment: Tip: you can resuse the character by creating a function (`;` are line breaks): `func WrapDoubleCharQuotes; let cchar = nr2char(getchar()); return 'i"'.cchar.cchar'"<ESC>'; endfunc; nnoremap <Leader>" WrapDoubleCharQuotes()`